# Postgresql calculate kernel share memory?

Tags: linux, memory, database, postgresql, kernel

We are running `PGSQL 9.2` and following are hardware specs

```
OS: CentOS7 64bit
CPU: 24
Memory: 32GB
Disk: SSD
```

I want to calculate shmmax/shmall values then what would be the good way? I google it and people saying 50% of Total memory. But on my box i have only PGSQL running then why not 80% of total memory?

Can i configure `kernel.shmmax` 28GB?  and keep 4G for Linux OS.

What do you suggest?

Comment: You'd miss out on being able to cache the DB related files in memory. Memory is quicker than disk! Linux will need some memory for itself to do that caching in

Comment: `4G` should be enough right?

Comment: How big is the database in total?

Comment: Max it will go `20GB` currently `2G`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shmmax` and `shmall` are not allocations, they are control knobs in the kernel that allow you to control the maximum shared memory segment size and the number of shared memory pages.

Quoting from the [sysctl documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt):

```
shmall:

This parameter sets the total amount of shared memory pages that
can be used system wide. Hence, SHMALL should always be at least
ceil(shmmax/PAGE_SIZE).

If you are not sure what the default PAGE_SIZE is on your Linux
system, you can run the following command:

# getconf PAGE_SIZE

==============================================================

shmmax:

This value can be used to query and set the run time limit
on the maximum shared memory segment size that can be created.
Shared memory segments up to 1Gb are now supported in the
kernel.  This value defaults to SHMMAX
```

I would recommend taking the suggestions you were given on the settings of these sysctl variables, as they are essential for being able to further tune PostgreSQL, and the recommendations are often more than adequate for the needed tasks. =)

Once those sysctls are set, setting `shared_buffers` to 25% of RAM, and `effective_cache_size` to 75% in your `postgresql.conf` will get you off to a great start towards using the RAM on your server effectively.

I also recommend following the PostgreSQL Wiki entry on [Tuning Your PostgreSQL Server](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server), or getting Greg Smith's PostgreSQL 9.0 High Performance book for further information on proper tuning and care of your server. =)